# PHP while loop not showing first item?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm just trying to show a basic list or items from my database but for some reason its not showing the first item so if there is only one thing in a category it doesn't show anything but if there's 2 it will show one item. I've added the code below.

query

```
 //this query will fetch 4 records only!
 $latestVideos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5")or die(mysql_error());

 $posts = mysql_fetch_array($latestVideos);
```

While loop

```
 while($posts = mysql_fetch_array($latestVideos)){

 $dateFormat= $posts['video_date'];
 $newDate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dateFormat));

 echo $posts['video_title']
 echo $newDate;
 echo $posts['video_embed'];
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` is used to return a row of the array at each iteration of the while loop.

The extra `mysql_fetch_array` takes the first row into post, and in the first iteration of the while loop it puts the second row into the post.

This is what you should be doing.

```
$latestVideos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5")or die(mysql_error());

 while($posts = mysql_fetch_array($latestVideos)){
 //do stuff here
 }
```

Comment: so could i just do $posts = $latestVideos ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's been bugging me for a while

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the first time you call "$posts = mysql_fetch_array($latestVideos);" the first row is retrieved and removed from $latestVideos. and the while loop then loops through the other rows.

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching once with the mysql_fetch_array, but then not using the results.  You're reading the first row and then throwing it away.

```
$posts = mysql_fetch_array(...); # Reads 1st row
while ( $post = mysql_fetch_array() ) { # reads 2nd-Nth row
}
```